# performSelector not called in iPhone 5 and 7 Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c

The below code asks for camera permission and displays a video. The function videoFinished has to be called after 9 secs. This does not work in iphone 5 and 7 plus.

```
       [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted){
       if(granted)
       {
           dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               [self.player play];
               [self performSelector:@selector(videoFinished) withObject:nil afterDelay:9];
           });

       }
       else
       {
           dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              [self noPermission];
           });
       }
```

**EDIT**

```
               [self.player play];
               [self performSelector:@selector(videoFinished) withObject:nil afterDelay:9];
```

This code also doesn't call the videoFinished method.

Comment: Where does it work?  Are you saying that `[self.player play]` is called but `videoFinished` is not?  Can you show us the code for `videoFinished`?

Comment: It works in iPhone6S.

Comment: [self.player play] works but videoFinished is not called

Answer (score 2):

`dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()` when you already in main queue, locks it.
Use `dispatch_async`.

And use `dispatch_after` snippet instead of `performSelector:...afterDelay`

Comment: I debuged and I found that the problem is with performselector. Is perform selector the best way to call a function after a delay or not?